# Node JS write response

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, webix

Can't figure out how to write a response to the server.

Right now i have a Login form that sends data to the server. On the server side i check if that data have the same value as the data in .json file and if everything is correct i want to send a response.

```
 if (login == "login") { // if POST request comes wiht 'login' parameter
            fs.readFile("JSON/DB.json", "utf8", function (err, data) {
                
                var jsonFileArr = []; // Data from .json
                jsonFileArr = JSON.parse(data);
                
                var logPost = loginData.log; // 'log' data from request
                
                
                var gotData = jsonFileArr.find(function (obj) {
                  // Search for the same 'log' data in .json
                    return obj.log === logPost; 
                });
                
                if (gotData === undefined) { // No same log
                    console.log("ERROR: Wrong 'log' or 'pass'")
                }
                else if (gotData.log == logPost) { // if there is the same 'log' , 
                                                   // check for same 'pass'
                    
                    
                    if (gotDaten.pass == passPost) { // Same 'pass' found , send the response
                       
                        console.log("Send Response");
                        
                        
                        response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', });
                        var resObject = { "status": "OK" };
                        var json = JSON.stringify(resObject);
                        response.end(json);
                        console.log(json);
                    }
                    else
                        console.log("ERROR: Wrong 'log' or 'pass' ");
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            console.log("Wrong request");
        }
```

The response is not being send , maybe there is a problem with how i have set up Node http server. How to properly write  a server response ?

Also when i try to use `response.write()` it gives me an `write after end` Error.

This is the whole Node JS server : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cpko7ryr/5/)

**FIXED**

Found the problem , i just had to move my code to where the pages are being called , and make a `else if`  loop instead of `if`

Comment: What data you want to send to client and  did you do res.send(), to send response?

Comment: @abdulbarik , trying to send json , and then show the message  with alert().

Comment: Did you try res.send()?

Comment: isnt res.send() belongs to express ?

Comment: I modified the answer, please check it

Answer (score 1):

You can use `response.setHeader(name, value)` with `res.send(data)`

Try this

```
if (login == "login") { // if POST request comes wiht 'login' parameter
  fs.readFile("JSON/DB.json", "utf8", function(err, data) {

    var jsonFileArr = []; // Data from .json
    jsonFileArr = JSON.parse(data);

    var logPost = loginData.log; // 'log' data from request


    var gotData = jsonFileArr.find(function(obj) {
      // Search for the same 'log' data in .json
      return obj.log === logPost;
    });

    if (gotData === undefined) { // No same log
      console.log("ERROR: Wrong 'log' or 'pass'")
    } else if (gotData.log == logPost) { // if there is the same 'log' , 
      // check for same 'pass'


      if (gotDaten.pass == passPost) { // Same 'pass' found , send the response

        console.log("Send Response");


        response.setHeader(
          'Content-Type', 'application/json');
          response.status(200);
        var resObject = {
          "status": "OK"
        };
        var json = JSON.stringify(resObject);
        response.send(json);
        console.log(json);
      } else
        console.log("ERROR: Wrong 'log' or 'pass' ");
    }
  });
} else {
  console.log("Wrong request");
}
```

Comment: Get Error : Can't set header after they are sent.

Comment: If this is the final `send response` code then error should not come and if you are doing something with `response` else after this code then you will get the error.

It's working fine for me

Comment: I think i have messed up something on the server side and somewhere the response is not being closed. I have posted a jsfiddle with my server side code. If you have time can you please check it ? It is not big.

Comment: your `sendFileContent` function call during this request?

Comment: I'm not sure , but that could be the problem. With this function  i call the html pages. Is there a way to test it ?

Comment: So you need to make sure you have to send only one response. Write your code in modular fom which is easy to readable and debug

Answer (score 1):

If you're using express you may use just `response.json(json)`